# Display a single image with combination of either List<byte[]> or List<BitmapImage> Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0

My application scans multiple pages and stored as a list of byte[]. I can save all elements of list as  jpg file, it works fine. Now, I would like to display and save a single image combination of List<Byte[]> or List<BitmapImage>.

I could combined list of byte[] and it create a big byte[] but does not display or save combined images.

Any kind of hints/sample/url would be helpful.

Comment: One way, though probably very slow, could be to convert every image into `WriteableBitmap` objects (that gives you access to individual pixels), and from there combine them into a single WriteableBitmap

Comment: @KooKiz. Thank you. Could you give me any alternate solution?